# Daylight saving in Debian 9

Tags: debian, date, lxde, ntp, timezone

I would like to know how to enable Daylight saving support for Debian 9 with LXDE. My timezone is set to Europe/Rome. However my clock is one hour ahead and - considering Daylight saving - it shouldn't.

Running `date` from the terminal I get:

> Mon 25 Feb 11:30:40 CET 2019

With `date --utc`:

> Mon 25 Feb 10:30:40 UTC 2019

Correct UTC time from https://time.is/it/UTC should be:

> Mon 25 Feb 09:30:40 UTC 2019

Comment: Dual booting with Windows, not using NTP or NTP blocked in firewall?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes, I'm dual booting with Windows. I just noticed that ntpdate is not working and it gives me this error `ntpdate[2883]: no servers can be used, exiting`. Moreover the Bios was set to the result of `date --utc`. I changed it to correct UTC. Now I've got correct time, but at startup Linux said something about hardware clock being incorrect.

Comment: ntpdate shows that message by default if I am not wrong. You will have the time problem each time you come from Windows....does installing `chrony` fixes your time?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I don't know how `chrony` works. I'll try to read some docs. I'll let you know. Thanks for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: there is no Daylight saving time in Winter in Europe, so your question is probably not about DST, but the difference between *local* time and [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Many Linux distributions will store the time in the system's builtin Real Time Clock (RTC) at the halt/reboot phase and read it at boot.

Below, 1. is probably not used anymore, so if not sure try 2. first.

1. Usually this was done with the [`hwclock`](https://manpages.debian.org/util-linux/hwclock.8) command. This command on *first* usage, will create the file `/etc/adjtime` and among other values, store an information: if the RTC is to be considered as UTC or local time. UTC is probably the default, since it has always been the time Unix cares about, keeping UTC internally, computing localtime from UTC when needed. Now since at least historically Windows was using local time, it stores local time on the RTC. So if the wrong default for your use case (dual boot) was chosen, you could have altered it with (after correcting time):

   ```
   hwclock --systohc --localtime
   ```

   The way `/etc/adjtime` is used anyway (clock drift correction...), it's best to delete this file before having changed the time and using this command (which will recreate it).
2. Today, with `systemd` attempting to cover all bases, `systemd` also provides [tools for setting time](https://manpages.debian.org/systemd/timedatectl.1). So the modern equivalent which also uses `/etc/adjtime` should be instead:

   ```
   timedatectl --adjust-system-clock set-local-rtc 1
   ```

   This will re-read the RTC but consider it to be local time and also save the setting.

All this doesn't prevent you to use [`ntpdate`](https://manpages.debian.org/ntpdate/ntpdate.8) (one shot sync) and [`chronyd`](https://manpages.debian.org/chrony/chronyd.8) (or [`ntpd`](https://manpages.debian.org/ntp/ntpd.8) or [`openntpd`](https://manpages.debian.org/openntpd/openntpd.8) ...) to synchronise time with precise sources.